# React native calling a function from a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, onpress, pressable

```
     <Pressable onPress={()=> {
            if(newID) {
              EditPress(newID)
            } else {
              AddPress
            }
          }}
            style={styles.logBox} >
           <Text style={{ textAlign:"center",bottom:12,fontWeight:"bold"}} > Save </Text>
    </Pressable>
```

I've been trying to make a component in react native which can either edit a movie or add a new movie to my List. I want to use an onPress function to call either of functions I created for fetching data. How can I use both functions with an if/else statement inside onPress. Especially when one of the functions will get parameters -which is the id for the movie I want to edit-  and another function will not get any parameters.

Comment: It's really important, when using JSX, to keep straight when you're working with JSX elements and when you're just working with JS. Inside the arrow function body, it's the latter (it doesn't even have the single-expression limitations of a directly interpolated value).

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Pressable onPress={()=> {
    if(newID) {
      EditPress(newID)
      return // using early returns, so that you don't need else is a good practice.
    } 
    AddPress()
  }}
  style={styles.logBox} >
    <Text style={{ textAlign:"center",bottom:12,fontWeight:"bold"}} > Save </Text>
  </Pressable>
```

You need to call Addpress by adding (). And I don't know where you are getting the newID from, but you might have to pass that as a parameter to onPress (add it inside the () before the arrow)
You can also extract the function from the jsx and define it earlier:

```
pressHandler = ()=> {
  if(newID) {
    EditPress(newID)
    return // using early returns, so that you don't need else is a good practice.
  } 
  AddPress()
```

You can then call it in the onPress, which I find easier to read.

```
  <Pressable onPress={pressHandler} style={styles.logBox} >
    <Text style={{ textAlign:"center",bottom:12,fontWeight:"bold"}} > 
      Save 
    </Text>
  </Pressable>
```

If you need to pass args to PressHandler:

```
<Pressable onPress={() => pressHandler(args)} style={styles.logBox} >
```